# Entity Framework v4 Code-Only Connection String

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, code-first

I have recently begun to use the EF v4 Code Only library for some projects I am working on. However, I have run into a bit of a snag. I can't seem to figure out the proper format for the connection string. I have used the following code to build the connection string:

```
string connectionString = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
    ProviderConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        DataSource = "localhost",
        InitialCatalog = "ASM_Testing",
        IntegratedSecurity = true,
        Pooling = false
    }.ConnectionString
}.ConnectionString;
```

However, using it results in the following error:

```
Specifications_for_EntityContext.When_logging_in_application_with_valid_app_role_and_password.Login_should_be_successful : System.ArgumentException : Some required information is missing from the connection string. The 'metadata' keyword is always required.
Stack Trace:
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ValidateValueForTheKeyword(DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions, String keywordName)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString)
   at ASM.Data.EntityContext..ctor(String connectionString) in C:\Users\Jon Rista\TFS\Advanced Service Management\Trunk\Main\Source\ASM.Data\EntityContext.cs:line 16
   at Specifications_for_EntityContext.Behaves_like_EntityContext_connected_to_a_database.TestableEntityContext..ctor(String connectionString) in C:\Users\Jon Rista\TFS\Advanced Service Management\Trunk\Main\Source\Tests.ASM.Data\EntityContextFacts.cs:line 165
   at Specifications_for_EntityContext.Behaves_like_EntityContext_connected_to_a_database.InitializeContext() in C:\Users\Jon Rista\TFS\Advanced Service Management\Trunk\Main\Source\Tests.ASM.Data\EntityContextFacts.cs`e`enter code here`nter code here`:line 160
   at ASM.Testing.xUnit.ObservationCommand.Execute(Object testClass) in C:\Users\Jon Rista\TFS\Advanced Service Management\Trunk\Main\Source\ASM.Testing.xUnit\ObservationCommand.cs:line 24
   at Xunit.Sdk.FixtureCommand.Execute(Object testClass)
   at Xunit.Sdk.BeforeAfterCommand.Execute(Object testClass)
   at Xunit.Sdk.LifetimeCommand.Execute(Object testClass)
   at Xunit.Sdk.TimedCommand.Execute(Object testClass)
   at Xunit.Sdk.ExceptionAndOutputCaptureCommand.Execute(Object testClass)
```

Seeing as I don't have any metadata...since I am using Code Only, I'm in a bit of a bind. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

The connection string generated by the builder classes is as follows:

> provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider
>   connection string="Data
>   Source=localhost;Initial
>   Catalog=ASM_Testing;Integrated
>   Security=True;Pooling=False"

---

**Working Example (based on accepted answers)**

It is necessary to use the ContextBuilder to create any instance of a context that uses a code-only mode. Here is a working example of this for those who are searching for an answer to the same problem:

```
protected override void InitializeContext()
{
    string connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        DataSource = "localhost",
        InitialCatalog = "Testing",
        IntegratedSecurity = true,
        Pooling = false
    }.ConnectionString;

    var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    var builder = new ContextBuilder<TestableEntityContext>();
    m_context = builder.Create(connection);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the resulting string? Or does it already blow up when executing this code?

Comment: @Henk: Added the connection string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use it:

```
var builder = new ContextBuilder<YourContext>();

using (YourContext context = builder.Create(new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourConenctionKeyInWebConfig"].ConnectionString)))
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew about ContextBuilder, but it did not cross my mind to use it in my unit tests for my EntityContext class. I think this will solve the problem though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand using code only approach you can't instantiate context by simply passing DB connection string to its ctor. Normally you would use `ContextBuilder` to create your context.

1. Define ctor taking `EntityConnection` in `EntityContext` class

   public EntityContext(EntityConnection connection): base(connection)
   {
   }
2. Create connection

   var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");
   var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
   connection.ConnectionString = providerConnectionString;
3. Use `ContextBuilder` to create new context

   var contextBuilder = new ContextBuilder();
   contextBuilder.Configurations.Add(...)
   var context = contextBuilder.Create(connection);

Comment: +1 Great answer. I read Gregoire's first, and marked it as accepted. Both of them answered my question, though. Thanks!